# Find a vector equation and parametric equations of the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through the origin and is parallel to the vector $\vec{u}=(2,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, parametric

anyone can help me? :<

Are there any equations that I could use in this question? I am so confused. I only know how to do the question if it changes "parallel" to "perpendicular" because I only know the equations for that...

thx

Comment: What do you know about (a) the form of the equations you want and (b) how you solve the problem with "perpendicular"?  Probably, you can do the same thing you would do for (b), except not change the direction vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector equation for a line with direction $ \ \vec{u} \ = \ \langle a, b \rangle \ $ passing through a point $ \ (x_0, y_0) \ $ (written as a vector from the origin, $ \ \langle x_0 , y_0 \rangle \ ) , $ is

$$ \langle x, y \rangle \ = \ \langle x_0, y_0 \rangle \ + \ t \cdot \langle a,b \rangle \ \ . $$

Such an equation expresses the location of each point on the line as a vector extending from the origin to that point.  (A line "parallel" to $ \ \vec{u} \ $ means that its direction is given by that vector.)

You will get the parametric form by writing out the corresponding equations for each component:

$$ x \ = \ x_0 \ + \ at \ \ ,  \ \ y = y_0 \ + \ bt  \ . $$

Note that if you solve the first equation for $ \ t \ $ and insert that result into the second equation, you will obtain the standard "point-slope" equation for the line, $ \ ( y - y_0 ) \ = \ \frac{b}{a} \ (x - x_0) \ . $